# How granular is FileSystemWatcher's Size NotifyFilter?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

If I set the NotifyFilter property of a FileSystemWatcher to "Size," how often will that FileSystemWatcher "sound the alarm" - every time the file grows by 1KB, or...?

Comment: Why don't you write a simple test?

Comment: That's a reasonable question/directive, but it would be nicer just to know what MS means by "change in size"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One byte.

This knowledge comes from personal experience with .Net 4.0 on Windows 7 64bit.